# JavaPlugin not being imported

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I'm trying to code a plugin using Java in the eclipse IDE. I have to extend JavaPlugin in the class but it is saying its not there and I need to make a new class with it. I tried importing JavaPlugin manually and its saying its not a package.

I've tried importing org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin but that didn't seem to work

```
imports org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
```

```
plubic class FirstSpigotPlugin extends JavaPlugin{
}
```

Is it supposed to be JConsolePlugin now? When I hover over the problem, it either says "Create class 'JavaPlugin' or "Change to JConsolePlugin"

(I'm trying to use Spigot, not bukkit)

Answer (score 0):

add spigot-api jar to your External JARs in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the spigot server/api jar file to your project on eclipse.

To add it to eclipse:

- Right-click on your project under the project explorer > Click "Properties"
- Select "Java Build Path" > Select the "Libraries" tab > Click "Add External JARs"
- Find and select the spigot server/api jar file and click open.
- Click the "Ok" button.